# Thread parameter ignored. Only paramless Sub of class executed

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, parameters

[SOLVED]
ByRef removed, param STRUCTURE (two members within) used. Works fine))

Can't find where`s an error.

param is a structure containing form and db-connection (active, open) for the dll to be able to do smth with data and show modal form, where the owner window is passed member _CallingForm.

Ext0 is an instance of the plugin.
There`s no problem with executing some similar plugins directly.
But in threads, there's parameter for the executing routine is ignored - **always**.

I hope, you'll help to find where I gone wrong.

```
'// Declaration of TServiceExtensionParams (in external interface dll, referred - there is ok).
'---------------------------------------------------
'Structure TServiceExtensionParams
'    Dim _CallingForm As System.Windows.Forms.Form
'    Dim _CONN As Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
'End Structure
'
'// Targetted Interface subs (in executing plugin,e.g. class library).
' !!!!!! 2 OVERLOADED SUBS, executing empty only.
' Public Sub Execute(ByRef param As Object) Implements VmS.RRC.IService.Execute
' Public Sub Execute() Implements VmS.RRC.IService.Execute

' Calling from the host app. Heh, trying to call.....((
' Here's almost full code except inserting thread into array to find thread by name (named as plugin's GUID) and abort later.

Dim param As New VmS.IExtension.TServiceExtensionParams
param._CallingForm = Me
param._CONN = CONN

Dim thr As New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf Ext0.Execute))
thr.Name = Ext0.GUID
thr.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
thr.Start(param) '<------- ???
```

I tried even pass Connection only. Tried both ByVal and ByRef, and even CType conversion to make AN OBJECT from structure))). Tried Object type in interface sub and TServiceExtensionParams - it was no difference in my case. No, it doesn't allow to pass anything.
Plugin executing it ***empty*** overloaded *Execute*.

Thank you, friends!

Comment: What does *[...] parameter for the executing routine is ignored* mean? That the overload of `Ext0.Execute` (e.g., `Ext0.Execute(param as Object)`) is not executed? That you receive an empty/non-initialized object? That you cannot cast `param` to `VmS.IExtension.TServiceExtensionParams`?

Comment: Yes, I tried CType (param,VmS.IExtension.TServiceExtensionParams). But executing only overloaded Public Sub Execute() Implements VmS.RRC.IService.Execute and tried Public Sub Execute(ByRef param As VmS.IExtension.TServiceExtensionParams) Implements VmS.RRC.IService.Execute

Comment: Nope, you need to have an overload of `Ext0.Execute()` declared as `Ext0.Execute(param as Object)`. Then cast `param` to whatever  is the actual Type.

Comment: I wrote: plugin (Interface IExport) has 2 overloads:  1) Public Sub Execute(ByRef param As Object) Implements VmS.RRC.IService.Execute 2) Public Sub Execute() Implements VmS.RRC.IService.Execute

Comment: It has problem only in threads. Other plug types are executing without troubles, each type has 3 or more overoads. I asked about a mistake in my code. Added comment to code above.

Comment: Remove `ByRef` from there.

Comment: Jimi, I have to leave two similar Execute() without params?

Comment: No, you need a `public Sub Execute(param As Object)` (no `ByRef`) and a `Public Sub Execute()`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Fixed. Removed ByRef (changed to ByVal), now it works with structure-param: TServiceExtensionParams. Thanks, Jimi!

Comment: If you REALLY need to keep `ByRef` for some reason (against your will :), you can change the Thread declaration in `Dim thr As New Thread(Sub() Ext0.Execute(DirectCast(param, Object)))`, then of course just `thr.Start()`. That is specific enough to identify the correct method overload. -- You shouldn't have `ByRef` there, though, so if you can remove it's good for you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again,Jimi. I'll try ByVal, but I guess byref not needed)

Comment: `ByVal` is the default, no need to specify that.